# Error with where I position the new text

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if it could post to the top and instead of posting on the bottom?

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html lang="EN" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xml; charset=utf-8 ">
        <title> Printing Statuses </title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form action = "StatusPoster.php" method = "get">
        <fieldset>
            <label>How are you feeling today?</label>
            <input type = "text"
                name = "userStatus" /><br>
            <button type = "submit">
                Submit
            </button>
        </fieldset>
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

StatusPoster.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html lang="EN" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xml; charset=utf-8 ">
        <title> Printing Statuses </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Posted Successfully!</h1>
        <?php
            $date=date("m-d-Y h:i:s");
            $userStatus = $_REQUEST["userStatus"];
            print "<p>$userStatus at $date</p>"

        ?>

        <?php
            $status = fopen("mystatuses.php", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
            $txt = " <span title='$date'>$userStatus</span><br>\n";
            fwrite($status, $txt);
            fclose($status);
            print "Click <a href='http://localhost/FacebookStatus/mystatuses.php'>here</a> to see all statuses"
        ?> 

    </body>

</html>
```

mystatuses.php

```
Click <a href='http://localhost/FacebookStatus'>here</a> to go back<br> <span title='09-04-2015 10:22:30'>Alright</span><br>
 <span title='09-04-2015 10:23:02'>Good</span><br>
 <span title='09-04-2015 10:23:07'>Bad</span><br>
 <span title='09-04-2015 10:26:02'>alright</span><br>
```

Comment: I guess the mystatus.php will not let me post the full code. <pre> Click <a href='http://localhost/FacebookStatus'>here</a> to go back<br> <span title='09-04-2015 10:22:30'>Alright</span><br>
 <span title='09-04-2015 10:23:02'>Good</span><br>
 <span title='09-04-2015 10:23:07'>Bad</span><br>
 <span title='09-04-2015 10:26:02'>alright</span><br>
 <code>

Comment: Is that new code? Your formatting was a bit off so it didn't display correctly.

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is asking. If what could display at the top instead of the bottom?

Comment: Not that new. But I mean you have to have a server to do this.

Comment: @chris85 I have no errors on my end at all I just want the content to post at the beggining instead of end

Comment: I meant in your first comment, is that code different then the code in your question. Also unclear on the question still.